# java.lang.ClassCastException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, exception, object

i have two tables like `Doctor` and `shift`  Through Hibernate Query Language i select two `fields` from `Doctor` table and two fields from `Shift` table in a single Query 
 so i am facing a problem to Display that data. 
i written one `bean` calss for that like `DoctorShift` to convert the list into `List<DoctorShift>` i'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException` so what to do
give same idea.....

```
code is like this

Query qry="-----";//valid query

List<DoctorShift> list=(List<DoctorShift>)qry.list();
System.out.println(" Size of list is "+list.size());// i'm getting 2

DoctorShift ds=list.get(0);// here i'm getting Exception




qry="select s.shiftNameId,s.shiftName,d.doctorRegnumvar,"
      +"d.doctorFnamevar,d.doctorLnamevar,d.doctorstatus," 
      +"sm.shiftstatus,s.shiftTime from ShiftDaoBean s,"
      + "DoctorDaoBean d,DoctorShiftMappingBean sm where "
      +"d.doctorid=sm.doctoridfk and  s.shiftID=sm.shiftidfk"
      +" and d.doctorid=:doctorID ";
```

help me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you show your annotation class.

Comment: Actually i dint configure DoctorShift class anywhere i'm new to Hibernate if it is required tell me how to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want in 2 ways:

1) Create constructor in DoctorShift class that takes all necessary arguments and in your HQL query create object using this constructor:

```
qry="select new com.yourpackage.DoctorShift(s.shiftNameId,s.shiftName,d.doctorRegnumvar,"
      +"d.doctorFnamevar,d.doctorLnamevar,d.doctorstatus," 
      +"sm.shiftstatus,s.shiftTime) from ShiftDaoBean s,"
      + "DoctorDaoBean d,DoctorShiftMappingBean sm where "
      +"d.doctorid=sm.doctoridfk and  s.shiftID=sm.shiftidfk"
      +" and d.doctorid=:doctorID ";
```

2) Get the list of Object[] arrays instead of the list of DoctorShifts objects. Each array will represent row in the result set. For example:

```
Query qry="-----";//valid query

List<Object[]> list=(List<Object[]>)qry.list();
System.out.println(" Size of list is "+list.size());// i'm getting 2

Object[] firstRow =list.get(0);

System.out.println(firstRow[0]);// will output shiftNameId
System.out.println(firstRow[1]);// will output shiftName
...
```

In second case your query will still the same as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Else you can use ResultTransformer to load data in your bean. May be [this blog](http://keyurj.blogspot.com/2013/02/loading-unmanaged-entities-in-hibernate.html) will help